# Running multiple background processes in script

Tags: shell, unix, parallel-processing

I have a shell script of the following format :

```
cd /path/a/
make 
cd /path/b/
make
cd /path/c/
make
```

Each of the make commands are independent of each other in different directories. I would like to speed up the script by running the different make commands in background using '&'

```
cd /path/a/
make & 
cd /path/b/
make &
cd /path/c/
make &
```

Would this work? While the first make command is running, the directory has changed to /path/b/ in the next line. Will this affect the first make commend in the background?

**Edit**: I am doubtful if this method would actually make this process faster, and wonder if these need to be run in separate processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be fine. `make` also accept `-C` option to change its directory before reading the makefile. So you can do like this as well:

```
make -C /path/a/ &
make -C /path/b/ &
make -C /path/c/ &
```

Comment: Thanks. These make commands are truly running in parallel right... and not just one after the other in background?

Comment: It will certainly run in parallel if you have multi processor. With single processor this is going to be time-sliced parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `make` takes a `-f` command line argument where you can simply specify the makefile you want. So, this should work:

`make -f /path/a/makefile &
make -f /path/b/makefile &
make -f /path/c/makefile &`

Comment: This would work only if the make file would use absolute paths everywhere right

Comment: Ah, right. Looks like tivn's answer is more relevant in the case of relative paths.